# Passing PHP Variables with requireJS in phtml

Tags: magento2.2, phtml, requirejs

On my text.phtml template I'm trying to add js by requirejs but can't get the php variables to pass through with them coming up as undefined.

Relevant text.phtml

```
$_option = $block->getOption();
$txtValue = $_option->getNoOfTextbox();

<script type="text/x-magento-init">
{
    "*": {
        "Option_Customoption/js/charCount": {
        "id": "<?= $_option->getId(); ?>",
        "boxCount": "<?= $txtValue; ?>",
        "maxChar": "<?= $_option->getMaxCharacters(); ?>"
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

charCount.js

```
define(['jquery'], function($) {
      'use strict';
console.log('#engraving'+config.lineId+'_'+config.id);

      console.log(config.id);
      console.log(config.maxChar);
        console.log(config.boxCount);

function updateCountdown() {


    var count = document.getElementById('#id'+config.lineId+'_'+config.id)
    var remaining = config.maxChar - $(count).val().length;

    document.getElementById('count' + config.lineId + '_' + config.id).innerHTML = remaining;
}

$(document).ready(function($) {
    updateCountdown();
    $(count).change(updateCountdown);
    $(count).keyup(updateCountdown);

});
```

});

requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
  map:  {
    '*': {
      charCount: 'Customoption/js/charCount'
    }
  }
}
```

Can anyone tell me why the PHP variables aren't passing to the js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you need to wrap your JS in a return function:

```
return function (config) {
   ...
}
```

Try this:

```
define(['jquery'], function($) {
    'use strict';

    return function (config) {
        console.log('#engraving' + config.lineId + '_' + config.id);

        console.log(config.id);
        console.log(config.maxChar);
        console.log(config.boxCount);

        function updateCountdown() {


            var count = document.getElementById('#id' + config.lineId + '_' + config.id)
            var remaining = config.maxChar - $(count).val().length;

            document.getElementById('count' + config.lineId + '_' + config.id).innerHTML = remaining;
        }

        $(document).ready(function ($) {
            updateCountdown();
            $(count).change(updateCountdown);
            $(count).keyup(updateCountdown);

        });
    }
});
```